The number of solutions to quaternary quadratic form
Problem: Given a quaternary quadratic form $Q(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=d, d,x_i\in \mathbb{Z},i=1,2,3,4$, I want to know the number of solutions to the equation, is there any reference for this problem?
Example: Given $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2 =d$, the number of solutions to this problem is here.
I only found solutions to some specific cases of this problem and it seems they use different methods. I have no knowledge in this direction and don't know where to start. Are there any relevant books and papers on this topic?
